# Disable submit once Recaptcha is verified

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

I have a form with Recaptcha enabled. If the user does NOT verify the Recaptcha and hits submit he/she is prompted to verify by an error message. Then they verify but the submit button remains disabled and the form cannot be submitted. How can I remove the disabled attribute once the Recapthca is verified without the form being refreshed.

My code so far:

```
   $(".elq-form").validate({

  submitHandler: function (form) {
  var captcha = grecaptcha.render('evbox-recaptcha', {'sitekey' : 
  'my_key'});
   var response = grecaptcha.getResponse(captcha);

    //recaptcha failed validation
    if (response.length === 0) {
      grecaptcha.reset(captcha);
      $('#recaptcha-error').show();
      return false;
    }


    //recaptcha passed validation
    else {
      $('#recaptcha-error').hide();
      $('#submit').attr("disabled",false);
      return true;
    }
  }
});


<p class="field-p">
                  <div id="recaptcha-error" style="display: none">
                    <p>[[%site.text.recaptcha? &topic=`default` &namespace=`site`]]</p>
                  </div>
                  <div id="evbox-recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_key"></div>
                  <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="[[%site.button.submit? &topic=`default` &namespace=`site`]]" class="submit-button button button__primary" />
                </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the following:

```
var captcha = grecaptcha.render('evbox-recaptcha', {'sitekey' : 'my_key'});
var response = grecaptcha.getResponse(captcha);

//recaptcha failed validation
if (response.length === 0) {
  grecaptcha.reset(captcha);
  $('#recaptcha-error').show();
  return false;
}
```

reference: [reCAPTCHA V2 | Google developers](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

Comment: No, no difference

Comment: Still doesnt work . I have to refresh the page and refill the form in. Not a great user experience :(

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: try to strore your captcha. for Ex. `var captcha = grecaptcha.render('example1', {'sitekey' : 'your_site_key'});` then use `grecaptcha.reset(captcha)`

Comment: what would i put in place of example1?

Comment: the id the html tag which will render the captcha

Comment: Now i can submit without verifying recapthca. I have updated the code above.

Comment: remove the hash mark from the id `var captcha = grecaptcha.render('evbox-recaptcha', {'sitekey' : 'my_key'});`

Comment: Also don't forget to change the value of response variable `var response = grecaptcha.getResponse(captcha);`

Comment: Check the answer again now please.

Comment: I have amended the code- but still can submit without recaptcha :( .  my code is edited above

Comment: You have to exchange `var response` and `var captcha` lines

Comment: Thanks for your patience, still same result though. Dont know what the isssue could be? Updated code above

Answer (score 0):

have you tried "attr" instead of "prop"?

```
$('#submit').attr("disabled",false);
```

Ref: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Thanks nut no change. Disabled persists